# How to build a python package with setup.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, setup.py

I'm trying to build package so that i can install it simply with pip3 command. It is an open-source project. Can someone please suggest me how to make it work.

This is content of my setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='hawkeye',
    version='0.1.0',    
    description='A powerful scanner to scan your Filesystem, S3, MySQL, Redis, Google Cloud Storage and Firebase storage for PII and sensitive data.',
    url='e',
    author='Rohit Kumar',
    author_email='',
    packages=find_packages('src'), 
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'hawk_eye=hawk_eye:main',
        ],
    },
    license='Apache License 2.0',
    install_requires=['pyyaml', 'rich', 'mysql-connector-python', 'redis', 'boto3'],

    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Build Tools',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache License 2.0',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
    ],
    keywords='pii secrets sensitive-data cybersecurity scanner',
)
```

And this is my project structure, and i made this open-source, entire source code can be found here - https://github.com/rohitcoder/hawk-eye, you can raise a PR if you want :) but let me know how to make it work.

```
├── LICENSE
├── __init__.py
├── assets
│   ├── banner.png
│   ├── hawk-eye.jpg
│   ├── preview.png
│   └── preview2.png
├── connection.yml
├── connection.yml.sample
├── fingerprint.yml
├── hawk_eye.py
├── pyvenv.cfg
├── readme.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    └── hawk_eye
        ├── commands
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── firebase.py
        │   ├── fs.py
        │   ├── gcs.py
        │   ├── mysql.py
        │   ├── redis.py
        │   └── s3.py
        ├── internals
        │   └── system.py
        └── main.py
```

And hawk_eye.py which is in root folder is having this content

```
import sys
import os

# Add the root directory to sys.path
root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, root_dir)

from src import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main.main()
```

I'm getting this error

```
  Attempting uninstall: hawkeye
    Found existing installation: hawkeye 0.1.0
    Uninstalling hawkeye-0.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled hawkeye-0.1.0
  DEPRECATION: hawkeye is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for hawkeye ... done
Successfully installed hawkeye-0.1.0

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.2.1
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
(venv) rohitcoder@Rohits-MacBook-Pro hawk-eye % hawk_eye      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rohitcoder/Desktop/Projects/hawk-eye/venv/bin/hawk_eye", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('hawkeye==0.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'hawk_eye')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/rohitcoder/Desktop/Projects/hawk-eye/venv/bin/hawk_eye", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 202, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1126, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hawk_eye'
(venv) rohitcoder@Rohits-MacBook-Pro hawk-eye %
```

I tried restructuring the folder but everytime i am getting error like hawk_eye isn't module, it's happening for that file only, which is in root folder

Comment: You might want to check out [the official guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and [the sample project by PyPA](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject) for a modern file structure.

Comment: Try creating a folder named "hawk_eye" and put hawk_eye.py and __init__.py inside it, let setup.py outside

Comment: Also, we'd much prefer it if you can give your directory structure [as text](https://superuser.com/q/359723) and [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Please read [mre] and try to create a new, separate project with **as little as possible** in it that **directly reproduces the exact problem**, and talk us through **complete** steps to reproduce it (starting with creating a new venv).

Comment: @InSync I updated the structure and also provided the link of the exact source code repositories in my main question, https://github.com/rohitcoder/hawk-eye, can you please suggest something on this one?

Comment: @user316108 It didn't worked same error, can you please check the question again? I edited question with more detail and added repo link https://github.com/rohitcoder/hawk-eye

Comment: You shouldn't use `setup.py` these days anyway.

Comment: @AKX what should be used instead?

Comment: @user316108 The first comment has a link to the PyPA tutorial that uses modern methods (in that case, hatchling).

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it.

I added below line and remove "package_dir" and it started working, i'm also not sure, why. BTW, i followed this project's https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck/ setup.py

```
packages=find_packages(exclude=['ez_setup', 'examples', 'tests', 'tests.*', 'release']),
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `setup.py` to begin with – see the first comment to your original post.